# Can't find associated cloud project

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

Attempting to add on the DS Trix Addon to Google sheets, and I've followed these instructions (done everything up until step 11), but getting stuck on step 11iii.  I don't see the dialog pop up with the link to the cloud project - and when I input project ID it also can't find anything associated.

link to DS Trix Github: https://github.com/google/ds-trix-addon

> 11. The final step is to configure OAuth so that the addon can access your Web Query Reports on DoubleClick Search.
>
>     i. In the script editor, open the file Constants.gs. This file has all the configuration parameters that we will populate.
>     ii. In the script editor, go to Resources > Cloud Platform Project.
>     iii. A dialog should pop up with a link to the cloud project that this script is associated with. It will be of the form  - project-id-1234567890123456789. Click on this link to open the associated cloud project.

Any ideas?  the last time this code was updated was April 2018, so not sure if that's the reason why.

Comment: Your question is "off topic."  You'll need to do some debugging yourself.  You could also try contacting the GitHub repo owner.  Here is a link to the Apps Script troubleshooting documentation: [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting?hl=en](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

It looks that the step 11.iii is wrong as new Google Apps Script projects haven't a link to the default Google Cloud Project. The link is shown when a Standard Google Cloud Project has added to the Google Apps Script project.

Try to unstuck yourself by creating a Standard Google Cloud Project and add it to your script. For details see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects.